# Add text between date and time - PHP

Tags: php, datetime

Is it possible to add text between date and time in PHP ?

```
<?php
echo date();
?>
```

This will create
(07-06-2014 00:00) 
 But i want  (07-06-2014 at 00:00 hours).

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Derived from your example which you provided a bit late

```
echo date('d-m-Y \a\t H:i:s') . ' hours';
```

be sure to use the exact syntax given! Using double quotes `"` instead of single ones `'` will result in you getting a tab for `\t`, you'd than need to use `\\a\\t` for proper syntax as in the example below:

```
echo date("d-m-Y \\a\\t H:i:s") . ' hours';
```

This is due to how php quoting works and has nothing to do with date formatting, things in `'` don't get escaped while those in `"` do, so if you use `"` be sure to use double backslashes `\\`.

If it's a datetime object

```
echo $datetime->format('d-m-Y \a\t H:i:s') . ' hours';
```

if you already have it as a string

```
echo str_replace(' ', ' at ', $datetime) . ' hours';
```

Comment: `\a\t` returns `a` for me. Put another `\a\\t` works, though.

Comment: This is because while `t` is a `date` string element (number of days in a given month), escaping it as `\t` outputs a tab. This therefore needs extra escaping!

Comment: if I use strftime how can i do it??

Comment: @rybo111 that's because you used `"` instead of `'` for quoting, added the explanation to the example.

Answer (score 9):

yes you can.

```
$date=date("m-d-Y");
$time=date("H:i:s");
$display=$date.'at'.$time;
```

Comment: Perhaps change this to `$display=$date.' at '.$time;` Notice the spaces around `at`.

Answer (score 5):

\a\t didn't work for me, instead `\\a\\t` works very well

`date("d-m-Y \\a\\t H:i");`

Comment: That’s because you’re using double quotes. [Backslashes are interpreted differently inside single vs. double quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Inside single quotes, the backslashes remain backslashes; inside double, `\t` becomes a tab character, which `date` doesn’t understand.

Answer (score 3):

Strangely enough I wanted to put

`date("l the jS F Y");`

to read e.g. Monday the 9th January 2017 but instead I got "Monday 3106UTC 9th January 2017". I read the answer above from xception and changed this to `date("l \t\h\e jS F Y")`, which gave me "Monday h 9th January 2017", so I read the comment from rybo111 and changed this to `date("l \t\\h\\e jS F Y")` and it still didn't work as I now got "Monday he 9th January 2017".

After a bit of head scratching I worked out that if letters in the word also form part of the date() function, for example t = Number of days in the given month, these need to be double escaped, otherwise a single escape will suffice. Hence why "at" needs to be coded `\a\\t` and "the" as `\\t\\h\\e`.

Answer (score 0):

First please put the given date in ISO Format so that `strtotime()` can read it and then use `date()` function to format the date accordingly.

```
date('/*DATE FORMAT YOU WANTED*/', strtotime('/*ISO FORMATTED DATE*/'));
```