# Laravel date format to include of between the day and the month

Tags: php, laravel

How can I format the date to include **"of"** between the `day` and the `month` to print something like `16 of september`?

I cant find the exact syntax. What am I forgetting?

```
format('d ["of"] m')
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/41580088/6449040 ?

Comment: using php date('d')." Of ".date('F');

Answer (score 5):

This is how it can be done

```
date('jS \of F'); // this is how it prints 8th of August
```

Answer (score 2):

jS \of F     the format function is an alias of php's date http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2):

```
echo date('jS \Of F', strtotime('2018-09-16'));   //Outputs 16th Of September
```

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

j - Day of the month without leading zeros.

S - English ordinal suffix for the day of the month, 2 characters.

F - A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March

Also, in the doc, it is stated that:

> You can prevent a recognized character in the format string from being
>   expanded by escaping it with a preceding backslash. If the character
>   with a backslash is already a special sequence, you may need to also
>   escape the backslash.

The statement above explains why we have `\Of`. `Of` is a recognized string. We can also do `\O\f` and still get the same result.

Comment: And now I am wondering why anyone would down-vote this answer. Have some decency and state your reason.

Comment: People are going to upvote/downvote as they wish; best not to get too bothered by it. Your answer is a good explanation, but it also came after 2 upvoted answers that also do a good enough job explaining.

Comment: @TimLewis... People shouldn't be allowed to mislead others just because they can. Left for me, downvoting should only take effect when a good reason has been presented...just like when you edit someone's post. You don't just do things because you have the power to. Also, the answers that came before this did very little/nothing in explaining and that is exactly why I attempted to answer. I'll take your advice and not be too bothered about irrational down-voting.

Comment: Upvotes/downvotes are anonymous, so people can do with them as they please. Someone clearly thought your answer was worthy of a downvote, did such and moved on. And while the other answers maybe didn't explain themselves very well, anyone that understands escaping will understand the answers and why they work. But I digress; keep posting good answers. If they're useful, people **will** appreciate it; let the rep loss/gains be a secondary thing.

Comment: Thanks once again. Now, away from the bitterness of down-votes...  When you say upvotes/downvotes are anonymous, were you in any way referring to my opinion about SO keeping them pending until after review?

Comment: Nope, what I mean is that you can't tell who voted on what, and for good reason; it prevents witchhunts/arguments/etc.

Comment: OK. Cool...Understood.